# Handling a .dat file created by another application

Tags: c#

I need to write an application which uses data stored in a .dat file created by another application. Basically the app which creates the .dat is a freeware app which collects info from an online game and stores the info. It also does some processing of the data. What i am planning to do is create a team tool which makes use of the stored data and do some further processing using our personal game knowledge.

Now i know what are the possible contents of the .dat file but not sure how i can read the data from it. I would appreciate any help on how to extract all the data from this .dat file. Not asking to be spoon fed with all code but step wise instructions on how to go about this would be really appreciated.

If you need any further info please do ask

Regards

EDIT: Opening the .dat file in wordpad i get the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ1OH.jpg

Comment: can you provide more info on the file format? is it binary or text?

Comment: Without knowing the file format youll either have to be very lucky or spend a fair amount of time figuring it out.

Comment: I agree with other Chris. Try talking to the developers of the app that is outputting that file and they may be willing to give you the file spec. I'm assuming it is written by the gaming community and they are usually pretty willing to share if they'll get another cool tool out of it.

Answer (score 4):

If the file is a text file where you would like to parse strings, you can use a `StreamReader`, like this:

```
using (var textFile = System.IO.File.OpenText("yourfile.dat"))
{
    string line = null;           
    while ((line = textFile.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
         // Parse line.
    }
}
```

If you need to parse a binary format, you can use a `BinaryReader`, like this:

```
    using (var dataFile = new System.IO.BinaryReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead("yourfile.dat")))
    {
        try
        {
            // Parse your data file according to the known format.
            dataFile.ReadBoolean();
            dataFile.ReadInt32();
            // ...and so on.
        }
        catch(System.IO.EndOfStreamException e)
        {
            // Handle trying to read past the end of the stream
        }
    }
```

Comment: Will try this out and let you know Andreas. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you're going to need to use the [`System.IO.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class. Within this class, you have several different options available as to how to read the file contents. The simplest methods are probably [`File.ReadAllText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) or [`File.ReadAllLines()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx).

E.g.:

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText("MyFile.dat");
```

Or:

```
string[] contents = File.ReadAllLines("MyFile.dat");
```

Once you've got the contents in-memory, it's up to you to parse and handle them appropriately.

**Edit:** Both of these methods are used when dealing with text files. It looks like you're using a file that contains binary data -- use an appropriate method like [`File.ReadAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thanks, will try this and see how it works. One thing though, like i said in the OP i'm not sure how the .dat file is formatted. Opening the file in wordpad i get the following (just the top few lines):

Comment: The formatting of the file shouldn't affect reading the contents of the file. It may affect the processing/parsing of the contents, but that's a different question.

Comment: @Donut: presumably binary/text is going to make a difference to how the file is read...

Comment: @Shoaib You will either have to use trial and error to figure out the format or ask the author of the application for information about the file format.  If you could tell us what game you might find somebody with information your looking for.

Comment: Well it could affect reading as text if it contains \0 chars, could it not?

Comment: I've added a screen shot of the file opened in wordpad.    @Ramhound The game is GPRO, http://gpro.net . The tool which outputs the .dat is here http://mbjerg.dk/gpro

Comment: @David Mårtensson `\0` is just an ASCII control character, the `null` character. It usually just gets displayed as a box, but there's no problem in reading it.

Comment: @Shoaib at first glance I would say its simply a binary xml file.  The problem with that is you have to know the format to read it.  I can't visit those websites at my current location.

Comment: Thank you everyone, i'll try and work my way with the info you've provided so far. Will report back if i find a solution to this or not. I've tried to contact the author of the original program but he's reluctant to help out.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a binary file. It's some sort of serialised object list. If you can upload it somewhere so I can take a look at the contents, I can point you in the right direction. All of those squares are numbers that mean something to the decoder. Search google for a program called XVI32, it's a hex editor that will give you a better idea of what's inside the file. Some of those numbers involve such things as string length, etc. or are the actual numbers to which the System.Int32 text is referring. You're not getting anything of value from Wordpad.

**EDIT: here we go**

Every table begins with `[00 01 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff]` and some more numbers, then the header text

```
[3e (62)]"go, Version=2.9.20.22362, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
```

more numbers here,

```
[TableNameLength(byte)][TableName][NumFields(int)]
{[FieldNameLength][FieldName]}*NumFields
{[FieldType(byte)]}*NumFields
{[ExtraInfo]}*NotAllNumFields
```

The extra info is tricky. That depends on the type. The types I can see are: 0 (int), 1 (string), 4 (foreign key), 7 (multi-value, possibly blob). Type 0 has a byte indicating size, type 1 has nothing, type 4 has the foreign key reference, and type 7 has System.Collections.ArrayList in my case. After that, there is some more info, possibly related to keys and/or default values, before the data starts. Then finally every table ends with [0b (11)]

I think the length of strings is not just one byte, but the C# way of saving strings to binary, which does something fancy to indicate how many bytes are used, so watch that.

That's all I can give you for now, unless you want to hand over your data file.

Comment: ok, I found the program you're talking about, and looked at the default tracks.dat file. Every string begins with one byte indicating its length and is not null terminated. If it begins with "go.", it is a table, and there are two instances of it. The first contains some sort of info about the table's contents, the second contains a 32-bit integer indicating the number of columns, each of which is preceded by one byte indicating the number of characters in the name. ([8]"go.Track"[11 00 00 00 (17 columns)][4]"name"[6]"number" etc..) This is likely followed by info about the fields, then data